# Things that can be followed

Tags: single-word-requests

Within a directory of **people** I can only index people

Within a directory of **contacts** I can index people, companies, institutions, etc.

Is there any word with a broader scope? Mostly things one can *follow* within a social network, like: products, places, events...

Ideally something less broad than *stuff*

Comment: Subject, perhaps?

Comment: You're mixing concrete, permanent things (places, people) with ethereal, impermanent things (events), so I don't think you'll find anything better than 'items of interest', 'components', 'stuff'...

Comment: Well in the context of Facebook or a social networking system what you're referring too is functionally an "object." Objects can be processes(in the light of processes you're actually referring to a call upon that process, but that's semantics i guess) or actually variables. I guess the confusion comes from trying to mix logical components(math/programming) to language, which isn't always apples to apples. So yeah, if youre willing to blend thought processes it would be an "object."

Answer (score 0):

You could say *records* or *entities*.  These terms are used when thinking about database design.

**Edit**

I just looked at your title again.  Maybe *followables* would fit for what you want to say.